# Why is recording webcam with FFmpeg much faster with an input format?

Tags: ffmpeg, camera

Question is the title

It's a basic question, but one that I can't find clearly answered in google or the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-grabbing), which says:

> If you specify the input format and device then ffmpeg can grab video and audio directly.

This isn't explicit enough for a beginner like me and raises other questions. What does ffmpeg do when the input format isn't specified and why is it so slow? If ffmpeg can figure out the encoding, doesn't it just do so once?

### Examples

For completeness... I'm using an Rasperry Pi 4 with a Picamera2 to record 1080p

With input format, I get the full 30fps: `ffmpeg -input_format h264 -i /dev/video0 -codec h264_v4l2m2m test.h264`

Without the input format, I get about 5fps: `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec h264_v4l2m2m test.h264`

Note: it will run without the hardware acceleration option `-codec h264_v4l2m2m` but doesn't reach the full 30fps

### Formats

In response to @llogan's comment, the output of `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` is:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [2]: 'RGB3' (24-bit RGB 8-8-8)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [3]: 'JPEG' (JFIF JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [4]: 'H264' (H.264, compressed)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [5]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [6]: 'YVYU' (YVYU 4:2:2)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [7]: 'VYUY' (VYUY 4:2:2)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [8]: 'UYVY' (UYVY 4:2:2)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [9]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [10]: 'BGR3' (24-bit BGR 8-8-8)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [11]: 'YV12' (Planar YVU 4:2:0)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [12]: 'NV21' (Y/CrCb 4:2:0)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
    [13]: 'RX24' (32-bit XBGR 8-8-8-8)
        Size: Stepwise 32x32 - 2592x1944 with step 2/2
```

Comment: I've included it in the question now

Comment: ffmpeg may not have anything to do with the slowness. Refer to the console output to see which format ffmpeg is choosing by default. To see capture fps directly from v4l2 try `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=pixelformat=<your pixel format> --stream-mmap`, where `<your pixel format>` is the name of the format selected by ffmpeg by default. Use the equivalent name listed in `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`, such as `YU12`.